error, "SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory"
So, I'm quite new to coding, so bear with me. I run upon tutorial videos for installing SFML in visual Studio code, but it eventually gets to this point. I tried to follow the instruction. installing SFML, setting up a MingW64 compiler, adding mingw64/bin to my system path, and adjusting configurations. But then this shows up when I tried running it. I've been trying to comply it for hours since yesterday. But I just can't work the IntelliSense code to correctly locate the SFML library. The only difference I've seen since yesterday is the absence of a red squiggly line below the "Include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>". I'd like to know how to have the SFML library compile and run. Thank you.
Test.cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}",
                "C:/SFML-2.6.1/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "compilerArgs": ["-I C:/SFML-2.6.1/include/**"]
            
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile SFML executable",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test.exe",
                "-IC:/SFML-2.6.1/include/",
                "-LC:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test.cpp",
                "-lsfml-graphics",
                "-lsfml-window",
                "-lsfml-system"
            ],
            
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true,
            },
            
            
        }
    ]
}

tasks:Run Task
tasks:Run Task in Code Block
 *  Executing task: C:\winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5\mingw32\bin\g++.exe -o C:\Users\Altheo\SMFL/test.exe -IC:/SFML-2.6.1/include/ -LC:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/ C:\Users\Altheo\SMFL/test.cpp -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system 

C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphics
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/\libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphics
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphics
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-graphics: No such file or directory
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-graphics.a when searching for -lsfml-graphics
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/\libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-window: No such file or directory
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-window.a when searching for -lsfml-window
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/\libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsfml-system: No such file or directory
C:/winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

 *  The terminal process "C:\winlibs-i686-posix-dwarf-gcc-13.1.0-mingw-w64msvcrt-11.0.0-r5\mingw32\bin\g++.exe '-o', 'C:\Users\Altheo\SMFL/test.exe', '-IC:/SFML-2.6.1/include/', '-LC:/SFML-2.6.1/lib/', 'C:\Users\Altheo\SMFL/test.cpp', '-lsfml-graphics', '-lsfml-window', '-lsfml-system'" terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 


Uninstall winlibs and replace it with msys2. Msys2 not only lets you install the compiler, but also a compatible SFML.

If you are 1) new to C++, 2) on windows then I recommend you stop using "visual studio code" now. And switch to "visual studio community edition" and use vcpkg to install SFML into your project. You will have far less issues with your build environment that way and you can focus on having fun developing C++

Your title says error, "SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory" but there is no such error in your latest attempt. Now the significant error is this kind of error
skipping incompatible C:/SFML-2.6.1/lib//libsfml-system.a when searching for -lsfml-system

This means that the libraries you downloaded are not compatible with the build you are attempting. One reason for this would be that you downloaded 32 bit libraries when you are trying to do a 64 bit build (other reasons are possible too).
You are using VSCode and you are using MinGW. This means (if you followed official instructions) that you also used MSYS2 to install your compiler. If this is not the case then you should really uninstall everything, start again and this time use MSYS2.
The big advantage of MSYS2 is that it includes a tool known as a package manager. In MSYS2 this tool is called 'pacman'. Using a package manager ensures that you get a couple of things right, firstly that all when you install something all dependent software also gets installed and secondly that the version of the software that is compatible with your existing platform gets installed.
So my advice is to delete your existing SFML installation, install MSYS2 (if not already installed), read up on pacman, and the use it to install SFML. Finally adjust your c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json files for the new SFML installation.
